# Как пользоваться "Удалёнными сессиями" на Astra Linux?

Tags: linux, astra-linux

У меня есть две Astr'ы
Обоим включал "Разрешить удалённые сессии"

Потом "Завершить работу" -> "Новый вход" -> "Удалённый"

Открывается модальное с выбором устройств, одна астра видит другую.
Делаю двойной клик на ту удалённую.
Получаю черное окно.

приложу скрины

Расскажите пожалуйста как этим пользоваться, почему то не получилось самому найти информацию, все пишут про XRdp когда речь заходит об удалённом доступе.
Яж так понимаю здесь xrdp не причем.
Ожидал увидеть сессию удалённого устройства

[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeD8X.png)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

rdp здесь при чём (это проблема импортозамещения c сурдопереводом ;)  ), смотрите тут https://entnet.ru/client/soft/petite/client-part/programs/lan-programs/xpdp.html

если машины видят друг друга, то значит сервисы запущены, можете проверить командой nmap -Pn компьютер1, что открыты порты именно rdp 3389, может и vnc 5900. это выглядит примерно так:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
631/tcp  open  ipp
5432/tcp open  postgresql
5901/tcp open  vnc-1
```

так что читайте про настройку xrdp, remmina, freerdp. да и vnc тоже - vncmanager, tigervnc, x11vnc

вам надо будет подобрать параметры запуска. смотрите справочник по опциям командной строки xrdp, для начала.

ой. там еще вместо freerdp надо запускать xfreerdp

```
xfreerdp /u:** /p:**** /v:192.168.1*.*
```

и, возможно, придётся настраивать десктоп менеджер, тоже задачка.